# Mysql выборка при совпадении в нескольких строках

Tags: mysql

```
+-----------+-------+------------+
| option_id | value | product_id |
+-----------+-------+------------+
|        13 |    3G |          5 |
|        13 |    3G |          6 |
|        57 |  2 ГБ |          5 |
|        57 |  2 ГБ |          7 |
+-----------+-------+------------+

SELECT 
    product_id
FROM 
    options 
WHERE 
    (option_id=13 AND value in('3G', '4G')) AND (option_id=57 AND value in('2 ГБ', '4 ГБ'))
```

Нужно выбрать id товарв у которого option_id(13) = value(3G) и option_id(57) = value(2 ГБ)

Тоесть выбрать нужно product_id(5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT /* DISTINCT */ t1.product_id
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t1.product_id = t2.product_id
  AND (t1.option_id, t1.value) = (13, '3G')
  AND (t2.option_id, t2.value) = (57, '2 ГБ')
```

или

```
SELECT product_id
FROM table
WHERE (t1.option_id, t1.value) IN ( (13, '3G'), 
                                    (57, '2 ГБ') )
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT( /* DISTINCT */ option_id) = 2
```